# Elasticseach, Redis, Banco de dados Relacional ou tudo?

Tags: redis, elasticsearch

Estou começando a trabalhar com o *Elasticsearch* e pelo que eu olhei ate agora na net me trouxe algumas duvidas.

1. Qual a diferença entre o Elastic e o *Redis*?
2. É vantajoso trabalhar com um banco relacional + o Elastic?
3. É possível e se for tem vantagens em trabalhar com o Elastic + Redis, Elastic + DB Relacional ou Elastic + Redis + DB Relacional?
4. Quando é indicado um e não o outro?

Comment: Ih, melhor separar isso aí em várias perguntas. E também, cuidado pra que isso não possa ser levado pro lado opinativo.

Comment: Pensei em separar mas deixar esse tipo de conteúdo em um lugar so ajuda em busca de posteriores, e sobre as opiniões, acho q fui direto, não perguntei qual é melhor que o outro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os 3 são coisas diferentes que podem ser entendidos como um pool de soluções que utilizados em conjunto podem solucionar problemas de arquitetura e escalabilidade para aplicações que necessitam de um grande desempenho (quando possuem muitos acessos simultâneos, busca constantes, realtime, etc).

O Redis você pode utilizar para várias finalidades como comunicação entre processos (imagine que você possui um sistema que parte é Node.js, Java e PHP, e você precisa comunicar tudo isso, o redis iria ajudar nisso, com o Pub/Sub https://redis.io/topics/pubsub), deixar os dados na RAM para acesso mais rápido, sendo que ele replica no disco para persistência em caso de reiniciar o servidor por exemplo, chave valor e listas (inclusive com opção de range). Sem dúvidas o Redis é uma solução bem completa que conseguimos utilizar para solucionar muitos problemas de arquitetura.

Já no caso do Elasticsearch, a idéia não é guardar dados, e sim BUSCAR dados. O Elasticsearch e o Solr foram desenvolvidos encima do [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/), onde a idéia é organizar arquivos. Imagine que nesse contexto, você pode guardar apenas propriedades e índices que gostaria de usar para buscas.

Agora vamos a uma aplicação no mundo real, onde você precisa de desempenho usando Redis, Elasticsearch e um banco de dados relacional.

Você carrega as linhas de uma determinada tabela do seu RDB que possui um grande volume de busca no Redis usando chave valor (id=>linha de dados em JSON), você carrega o Elasticsearch com as propriedades inclusive para busca de geolocalização. Quando o usuário acessar o seu site / webservice, você faz a busca utilizando o Elasticsearch e devolve os índices, que irá usar para pegar os dados no redis, que está carregado em RAM. Tente imaginar isso funcionando em um ambiente que possui realmente muitos acessos simultâneos.

Quando o usuário atualizar alguma informação, replica isso no Elasticsearch e no Redis.

Lembrando que esse é apenas um exemplo das milhares de coisas de podem ser feitas.

Espero ter ajudado no entendimento.

Comment: Ajudou sim, mas uma outra coisa que vi muito na net foi eles usando o elastic como banco de dados e assim deixando de usar um relacional ou um outro não relacional como o mongo, pelo que vi de Redis isso não é um boa pratica mas o mesmo se aplica ao Elastic?

Comment: Então @João não existe uma bala de prata para tudo em arquitetura de software, é complicado falar que é errado, pois não sei o contexto aplicado 
 de quem está utilizando para armazenamento, mas se você olhar no próprio site do Elasticsearch, eles próprios de denominam como um motor de busca. O "normal" é utilizar focando na busca. No caso do Redis é a mesma coisa, eu não uso o redis para "armazenar" (bem entre aspas mesmo, pois quando você está guardando os dados, você está armazenando), eu uso para cache e comunicação entre processos em alguns casos.